# PSD to Joomla conversion tutorial

Tags: html, css, joomla, psd

I am new to Joomla and was going through several tutorials related to Joomla based designed. Although I have installed Joomla in my machine and have coded my PSD file into CSS/HTML 
I am presently stuck with how I need to integrate this file into the Joomla package. Joomla has a default index.php page which it shows how do I replace that with my HTML page ?

Comment: have you tried anything of your own so far? take a look at the structure of the Joomla template and start moving over code snippets bit by bit and it will start to pick up

Comment: [This](http://www.joomlaport.com/template-tutorials/joomla-template-tutorial-part-1-joomla-template-concepts.html) seems to be a good resource!

Comment: You'd have to see how to create a Joomla template. There are certain function calls at certain parts of the template to get the content from Joomla DB. That is how it happens in WordPress as well!

Comment: @djthoms - I wish I had helpful links that that when I first started :)

Comment: thanx @djthoms it too was a very helpful tutorial for me to get started with, however I have one more question should we manually upload the entire template into the extensions manager because it does not show up in the template manager

Comment: @Yoosuf unfortunately I am not terribly familiar with Joomla, I mainly theme for Drupal, Wordpress, and (almost exclusively) Magento!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to throw your design into a Joomla Template. [This tutorial should help, starting at step 4](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/).

To save time you can try finding a template that closely matches your design's structure and modifying it.

Within the `joomlaroot/templates/yourtemplatename/` folder you can edit the `index.php`, `templateDetails.xml` and any other files to get your desired look and feel. Any images you add to the design should be thrown in the template directory as well.

Make sure to only edit files in your template folder, or bad things can happen if you try to up date your Joomla installation in the future :)

Comment: Thanks the tutorial is very helpful, however the Joomla backend in the browser does not show the new folder I created inside the template folder. I created the templateDetails.xml file as well. Should I upload it using the extentions manager

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link. if you have any issue let me know.

[Creating a basic Joomla! template](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template)

[How to Create Your First Joomla Template](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/)

[How to Build a Joomla Template: Start to Finish](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-joomla-template-start-to-finish/)

[Create a Template with Joomla: Step by Step](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/create-a-template-with-joomla-step-by-step/)

[How to build Responsive Joomla Template?](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=733804)